# Is there any OpenTelemetry exporter for Appdynamics?

Tags: metrics, appdynamics, exporter, open-telemetry

I am doing some proof of concept to ingest traces and metrics to AppDynamics without installing Appdynamics agent. I have an application emitting prometheus metrics and traces. I could not find any Appdynamics documentation talking about opentelemetry Collector.

I could not find exporter in https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter either.

Can you please advise on how to use opencollector with Appdynamics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a Beta program now running for using AppDynamics with the OpenTelemetry Collector.

More details are available in the public docs: https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/Ingest+OpenTelemetry+Trace+Data

Answer (score 0):

AppDynamics have a fork of contrib project [here](https://github.com/Appdynamics/opentelemetry-collector-contrib) where there is an exporter but it isn't clear if it has been finished

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am compiling the code now. There is no documentation or reference about how to import metrics/traces in AppDynamics using this repo. Hoping to get some pointers from AppDynamics. Last commit was done 5 months back. hmmm..

Comment: It looks like, it is a stale repo. Last commit was made 5 months back. Also could not locate any real exporter implementation